# Click & Show - Tablet/Mobile

Tags: css, html, mobile-safari

So, Im currently trying to do this:

```
 <table class ="tablez">
 <tr>
 <th>Table Title </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <a tabindex="0" class="clickable">Click Me!</a>
 <div id="showedClickable">
 <p>This is showed when Click Me! is clicked.</p> 
 </div><!--EO showedClickable -->
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Heres the class

```
  #showedClickable {
 position:absolute;
 display:none;
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 }
```

Heres what happens when you click.

```
 a.clickable:focus + #showedClickable {

 display:block;
 }
```

It works fine on chrome on a laptop but when I try this on a mobile(iPhone) this doesn't work....What's the issue here?? How can I work around this,solve this?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you try a hover too? e.g.:

a.clickable:hover + #showedClickable . Mobile browsers interpret hovers as clicks.

Comment: @OliverBenns but If I implement 2  Click Me's and display different things on the same spot. If you click one and hover on the other both showings would overlap and look messy....What do you suggest I do in this case?

Comment: I think we need to see the code. Can you set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: @OliverBenns Here's what Im telling you: http://jsfiddle.net/Q83UE/

Comment: If user clicks one to see(most likely on the computer) when you hover on another one it overlaps, is there any way I can go around this? So its laptop/mobile friendly, like...Is there any way that when you hover the focus nullifies?

Answer (score 0):

I had simillar trouble to this. The problem is that the iPhone doesn't redraw siblings based on events in CSS.

Try nesting your elements like this and using a child selector rather than a sibling selector. It is also generally more semantic as the item you click is often a heading for what is shown.

Oddly enough the iPad supports hover as a click event,

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Click me</a>
        <ul>
            <li>This is showed when Click Me! is clicked.</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

li:hover ul {display: block;}
```

Comment: Yeah I know, my questions is, when Someone clicks the block, it appears, if the user is using a normal browser when the user hovers on Click Me2 and it overlaps (Like in this fiddle: jsfiddle.net/Q83UE )What do I do to hide one and show the other?